# MySQL_real_escape_string not adding slashes?

Tags: php, mysql, string, escaping

So I do this:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include("../loginconnect.php");
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[int]);
    $int = nl2br($_POST[int]);
    $query = "UPDATE `DB`.`TABLE` SET `interests`='$int' WHERE `user`='$_SESSION[user]'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

And let's say that $_POST[int] is "Foo' bar." The single-quote remains unescaped AND I get a MySQL error when running the script, due to the quote. What's wrong?

Comment: I also tried using $_POST['int'] with quotes, but that fails too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

m_r_e_s() RETURNS the escaped value, it doesn't modify the original.

```
$int = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['int']);

$query = "UPDATE ... interests = '$int' ...";
```

Note that I've added quotes around the `int` in the POST value. Without the quotes, PHP sees it as a constant value (e.g. define()). If it doesn't find a constant of that name, it politely assumes you meant it to be used a string and adjust accordingly, but issues a warning. If you had done

```
define('int', 'some totally wonky value');
```

previously, then you'd be accessing the wrong POST value, because PHP would see it as `$_POST[some totally wonky value]` instead.

Comment: But in the database, the data remains unescaped. Why?

Comment: Because the escaping is removed as part of going into the database. Escaping is only useful for the actual query portion, when you're building the SQL statement. After that, MySQL knows EXACTLY where things are, and there's no way for a "naughty" value to leak out. In a vague way, escaping is like handcuffs on a prisoner while transferring between facilities. Once the prisoner's in the new jail, the handcuffs are removed.

Comment: So the data is still safe, even though I can't see the slashes?

Comment: @Marc, I've taken the freedom of adding the quotes around the argument, I've assumed you forgot them.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the results of mysql_real_escape_string in your query.
Try doing this:

```
$int = nl2br(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[int]););
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should be using prepared statements. It has a slight learning curve over mysql_* functions, but is well worth it in the long run.
- You should quote your strings, like $_POST['int'] instead of $_POST[int].
- At the top of your file put error_reporting(-1);